# What do with Async in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have problem with async.
Result of this code from pic should be:

```
First:0
Second:2
Item ADD!
First:1
Second:2
Item ADD!
First:2
Second:2
Item ADD!
```

And here script should stop.

I know that code is to long but I can't put less.

```
connection.query('SELECT `keys`.*,`transaction`.*,`keys`.`id` as kid, `transaction`.`id` as tid  FROM `transaction` JOIN `keys` ON `keys`.`id` = `transaction`.`keys_id` WHERE `transaction`.`status_pay`= 1 and `transaction`.`status` = 1').then(function(rows){
                    rows.forEach(function(record) {
                        var offer = manager.createOffer('76512333220');  
                        inventory.forEach(function(item) {
                            connection.query('SELECT amount_two FROM transaction where id = \'' + record.tid + '\'').then(function(w){
                                console.log("First: " + w[0].amount_two);
                                console.log("Second: " + record.amount);
                                if(w[0].amount_two <= record.amount)
                                {
                                    if(item.market_hash_name == record.real_name)
                                    {
                                        var asid = item.assetid;
                                        connection.query('SELECT count(id) as wynik FROM used where asset_id = \'' + asid + '\'').then(function(wiersze){
                                            if (wiersze[0].wynik == 0) 
                                            {
                                                var employee = {
                                                        asset_id: asid,
                                                        trans_id: record.tid
                                                    };
                                                 connection.query('INSERT INTO used SET ?', employee).then(function(rows){
                                                    offer.addMyItem(item);
                                                    console.log('Item ADD!');
                                                    connection.query('UPDATE `transaction` SET `amount_two`= `amount_two` + 1 WHERE `id`=\''+record.tid+'\'').then(function(rows){

                                                    });
                                                });   

                                            }   
                                        });
                                    }   
                                }           

                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
```

[image]

Comment: you should consider adding promises to the mix. you also have no guarantee when the callback will fire.

Comment: Promises is another way of handling asynchronous behavior. I would not suggest using that before u learn the basic callback behaviors. It might look a bit confusing at start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a forEach where you do asynchronous stuff (do queries). The callback result of the db queries will be called when the db returns result. But by then, you have already looped the array to the end.
This is how node and JavaScript fundamentally works.

If you want to do asynchronous stuff like that, look at the `async.each` or `async.parallel` documentation. It provides a callback in the loop function argument, to tell your code that the iteration is done. Then the final result is collected to the 3:rd parameter of the `async.each`, which is a function that will be run once all iterations are completed.

Update:

You could look into joining your two select queries to not make too many requests to your database. That would give better performance also.

Code example:

```
connection.query(selectQuery).then(function (rows) {
    async.each(rows, function (record, next) {
        // perform the logic of each record!
        // Get or set data to db, calculate things etc. Ex:
        connection.query(saveQuery).then(function (err, res) {
            // this will tell async you are done with the record
            next(err, res);
        });
    }, function (err, result) {
        // here is error if any iteration went south,
        // or the final result: an array with what ever was passed into
        // the next function while iterating.
        // Pass results to where you want it. You can log it here if you want.
    });
});
```

Comment: Could You show me simple example with using mysql query?

Comment: What if I need sth like this:
`async.each(arrayOne, function (record, next) {
     async.each(arrayTwo, function (record, next) {
`

Comment: Then see both eaches as separate tasks, and you can run them in an async.parallel or similar.